# OpenCV python, how to pythonically apply an operation to a single channel?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

Assume I have an OpenCV image with dimension 1000x1000x3

Assume I want to apply the per pixel operation

```
if pixel == (255, 255, 255): 
     pixel = (0, 255, 0)
```

Clearly i could just write 2 for loops and do it that way. However, for loops accessing pixels in python are very slow.

I have been told there is a pythonic way to do things like this, for example `img = cv2.min(img, 255)` would find the minimum of the mat's pixel value and 255, effectively clamping the value range on a single channel image.

However, I am not sure how to apply a per pixel if conditional to each pixel in a similar fashion.

Comment: It's a numpy array, so just use indexing (if you're working with OpenCV in Python, it's a really good idea to familiarize yourself with numpy docs).   `pixel[pixel == (255,255,255)] = (0,255,0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use numpy conditions:

For example, replace even numbers in a 5x5 matrix by 42:

```
import numpy as np

a = np.arange(5*5).reshape((5,5))
print(a)
```

Out:

```
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
   [ 5,  6,  7,  8,  9],
   [10, 11, 12, 13, 14],
   [15, 16, 17, 18, 19],
   [20, 21, 22, 23, 24]])

a[a%2==0] = 42
print(a)
```

This yields:

```
array([[42,  1, 42,  3, 42],
   [ 5, 42,  7, 42,  9],
   [42, 11, 42, 13, 42],
   [15, 42, 17, 42, 19],
   [42, 21, 42, 23, 42]])
```

For your image, you need a bit more manipulation. it would be something like:

```
myImg = np.arange(1000*1000*3).reshape((1000,1000,3)) # replace with your image
colorVecs = np.reshape(myImg,(-1,3)) #so that each array element is a 1x3 vector
colorVecs[colorVecs == [255,255,255]] = [0,255,0]  #perform your operation

filteredImg = np.reshape(colorVecs,(1000,1000,3)) #back to a normal image
```

More info on numpy boolean masks [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.indexing.html#boolean-or-mask-index-arrays)

Answer (score 1):

Since OpenCV utilizes Numpy arrays to display images, we can we [Numpy slicing/indexing](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html) to access individual pixels or channels. For instance to apply an operation to a vertical/horizontal channel we can do this

To change the vertical channel at `50` to black

```
blank = np.full((200, 200), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
vertical = blank.copy()
vertical[:,50] = 0
```

To change the horizontal channel at `50` to black

```
horizontal = blank.copy()
horizontal[50,:] = 0
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Full code

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

blank = np.full((200, 200), 255, dtype=np.uint8)
cv2.imshow('blank', blank)

vertical = blank.copy()
vertical[:,50] = 0
cv2.imshow('vertical', vertical)

horizontal = blank.copy()
horizontal[50,:] = 0
cv2.imshow('horizontal', horizontal)

cv2.waitKey(0)
```